# How do I know whether a Task is canceled by a timeout or a manual trigger?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await, cancellationtokensource

Say I have the following Start and Cancel event handlers. How do I know who was the one who triggered the cancellation?

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private async void OnStartClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(5000);
            await Task.Delay(10000,cts.Token);

        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException taskCanceledException)
        {
            ??? How do i know who canceled the task here ???
        }
    }

    private void OnCancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Store in a field whether the cancel-button was clicked or not:

```
bool hasUserCancelled = false;
```

And reset this field before you start:

```
        hasUserCancelled = false;
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(5000);
```

Set it in the cancel-button click handler:

```
private void OnCancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    hasUserCancelled = true;
    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
}
```

The information that you wanted is now available in the catch:

```
    catch (TaskCanceledException taskCanceledException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(new { hasUserCancelled });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the `Debug.WriteLine(new { hasUserCancelled })` trick.

Comment: what does this anonymous class do?

Comment: It's a nifty trick to get a neatly formatted property-value paired log message, i.e. the output will say "{ hasUserCancelled = false }", depending on your log formatter, etc of course.